# The button of a Android project simply does not work

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing a small project of test, and I wrote the following code. I already created in the xml file, a button with id called "registerBtn".

I erased the imports of this source code to shorten space of this source code.

In the java file, I created a variable called mRegisterBtn, in the type of Button. Inside the method called onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) the mRegisterBtn receives the method called findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

However, in the mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener, the part of new View.OnClickListener appears in gray color, and it is not working when trying to test this code.

This image shows what I really mean. Please, perceive that the the part of new View.OnClickListener appears in gray color. It means a error. But trying to compile, this code runs, but the button simply does not work.

There is no error message in the Logcat.

The Java Lambda expression also does not work.

The button simply does not work.

Can anyone know how to fix this error, please?

[image]

````
```
public class Register2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mRegisterBtn;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register2);

        mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

        mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}```
````

````
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#007FFF"
        tools:context=".Register">
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: You need to use the activity context on the toast, not the application context.

Comment: Gray color simply means you can rewrite it as a lambda, `v -> Toast.makeText...`... If it doesn't work, your error is elsewhere

Comment: m0skit0 , thank you very much. 

Please, how would be this source code line:

Toast.makeText( ..................,"Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();